# Retrieve pod version from podspec or info.plist in to code

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, swift4, plist

I have created my own pod which has podspec file which contains s.version = "0.4.7", which I want programmatically into the code, so whenever app runs it sent pod version to the server.

Another place to get pod version is from below plist file which is "Bundle version string" 0.4.7

[image]

I have tried using `let version = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String` but it gets version from Apps Info.plist file.

Comment: `Bundle.main` is the app's bundle. I would suggest looking at the `Bundle` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle) to find out how to get the bundle for your pod. Shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez already tried but could not find directory "Support Files"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get your pod's version by specific the bundle of your lib.

Firstly, click to the `Pods Project` file, it will show all the lib, that you install by specific in `Podfile`. 
[image]

For example, I will get the RxSwift's version like this

- Step 1: Get the Bundle Identifier of RxSwift by click to RxSwift Target > General > Copy `Bundle Identifier` (org.cocoapods.RxSwift)
- Step 2: Get the version by this code

(note that the `org.cocoapods.RxSwift` is that you get from step 1)

```
if let version = Bundle(identifier: "org.cocoapods.RxSwift")?.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String {
    print(version)
}
```

And you can get the result like this

```
"4.3.1"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can retrieve bundle more explicitly: `Bundle(for: SomePodClass.self)`,
where `SomePodClass` is any class that is inside your pod.

Also you can turn it into extension inside your Pod for convenience:

```
public extension Bundle {
    class var somePodName: Bundle {
        return Bundle(for: SomePodClass.self)
    }
}
```

write some configuration file for your Pod:

```
public enum SomePodConfiguration {
    static var version: String {
        guard let version = Bundle.somePodName
            .infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String else { return "Unknown" }
        return version
    }
}
```

and finally get Pod version:

```
SomePodConfiguration.somePodName.version
```