# How to check for swift version from Podfile?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, react-native, cocoapods

I am trying to conditionally include a pod library based on the Swift version. Is there a way to check the swift version from the Podfile ?

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52809846/8201581

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find the swift version of the pod file.

[image]