# How to get the current pod library version in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, cocoapods

I'm developing a pod named MyPod, and in the podspec file I have the following configurations:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'MyPod'
  s.version          = '1.0.1'
  ...
end
```

Let's say I have a file in this pod named MyPodClass.swift, and in this file I want to get the pod version info dynamically so that when I change s.version to 1.0.2 in the future I don't have to modify my code.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Looks like you need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52809637/2227743)

Comment: @EricAya It works only when the pod is imported as a dynamic framework. If it is a static framework, Bundle(identifier:) returns nil and Bundle(for:) returns the main bundle.

Comment: @P.Tsin did you find a better way?

Answer (score -1):

Open the terminal, cd into the folder where the podfile is and run `pod outdated`?